# . It’s working fine when I pass 10-15 input but taking more than 5 minutes for 30 input. I need to make it work for 100 inputs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-performance

Here is my ask:

1. Go through the code and understand it.
2. As first solution, query should complete within 10 secs for 30 input
3. It should be working with good performance for 100 input as well.

My code:

```
/**************************************************
Populating the Array values in table variable
**************************************************/
DECLARE @PUZZLE table(  
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
   Value int NOT NULL)
/****Sample 1*****/
INSERT INTO @PUZZLE (value)
--SELECT 0 UNION ALL
--SELECT -22 UNION ALL
--SELECT -33 UNION ALL
--SELECT -44 UNION ALL
--SELECT 55 UNION ALL
--SELECT -100 UNION ALL
--SELECT 100 UNION ALL
--SELECT 10 UNION ALL
--SELECT -30 UNION ALL
--SELECT -60 UNION ALL
--SELECT -60 UNION ALL
SELECT -60 UNION ALL
SELECT -10 UNION ALL
SELECT 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 10 UNION ALL
SELECT -10 UNION ALL
SELECT 0 UNION ALL
SELECT -22 UNION ALL
SELECT -33 UNION ALL
SELECT -44 UNION ALL
SELECT 55 UNION ALL
SELECT -100 UNION ALL
SELECT 100 UNION ALL
SELECT 10 UNION ALL
SELECT -30 UNION ALL
SELECT -60 UNION ALL
SELECT -60 UNION ALL
SELECT -60 UNION ALL
SELECT -10 UNION ALL
SELECT 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 10

/**************************************************
Populating possible hierarchy/path
**************************************************/

DECLARE @puzHierarchy table (parentid int, childid int,value int)

INSERT @puzHierarchy (parentid,childid,value)
SELECT *-- INTO #puzHierarchy
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS ParentId,ID AS ChildId, Value 
    FROM @PUZZLE 
    WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @PUZZLE)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.Id,C.ID,C.Value
    FROM @PUZZLE B
    JOIN @PUZZLE C
        ON C.ID > B.ID AND C.ID < (B.ID + 7)
) A

--SELECT * FROM @puzHierarchy order by parentid

/*******************************************************
Logic using recursive CTE to get the path with max value
*******************************************************/
;WITH children AS
(

   SELECT ParentId
            ,CAST(ISNULL(CAST(ParentId AS NVARCHAR) + '->' ,'')  + CAST(ChildId AS NVARCHAR) AS NVARCHAR(Max)) AS Path
            ,value As PathValue
   FROM @puzHierarchy
   WHERE ChildId = (SELECT MAX(ChildId) FROM @puzHierarchy)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.ParentId
            ,list= CAST(ISNULL(CAST(t.ParentId AS NVARCHAR)  + '->' ,'')  + d.Path AS NVARCHAR(Max))
           ,(t.value+d.PathValue) As PathValue
   FROM @puzHierarchy t
   INNER JOIN children  AS d
      ON t.ChildId = d.ParentId
   )

SELECT [Path],PathValue
FROM children c
WHERE ParentId IS NULL 
    AND c.PathValue = (SELECT max(PathValue) FROM children WHERE ParentId IS NULL)
```

Comment: please explain your problem , what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: Hi i need to It should be working with good performance for 100 input. now its taking so much time for 20 to 30 inputs. Can you please suggest

Comment: could you elaborate this question, so anyone could suggest something good?

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, its taking so much time to get executed for that 20-30 inputs i want to improve the performance of the query. Please suggest me how to improve that.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A. Your code goes through too many cycles/data unrelated to result you want. 
B. After running your sample data, the results are not accurate.

Parentid    Path PathValue

NULL        1->3->4->6->10->12->13->19->20  145

NULL        1->3->4->10->12->13->19->20 145

The first result is wrong.

Basically you just want starting from ParentId IS NULL and ChildId = 1, among ParentId = 1 finding which ChildId has the MAX value, this ChildId becomes ParentID to find next MAX value, and so on.

```
;WITH cte_base AS (SELECT Parentid
                    , Childid
                    , Value
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Parentid ORDER BY Value DESC) AS Rownum
                FROM #puzHierarchy
), cte_re AS (SELECT ParentId
                , Childid
                , CAST(CAST(ChildId AS NVARCHAR) AS NVARCHAR(Max)) AS Path
                , Value As PathValue
                , Rownum
        FROM cte_base
        WHERE Parentid IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.parentid, b.childid
                , CAST(Path + '->' + ISNULL(CAST(b.parentid AS NVARCHAR)   ,'')  AS NVARCHAR(Max))
                ,(b.value + r.PathValue) As PathValue
                , b.Rownum
        FROM cte_base AS b
        INNER JOIN cte_re AS r
            ON b.Parentid = r.childid
        where b.Rownum = 1
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_re
```

(I changed your sample table variable to a temporary table.)